# visual studio 2013 stop working

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013

I installed Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8.1 as an administrator. After it installed, it stopped working. When I opened it to start a new project this message came up.

> **A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.**
>   **Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.**

And it said than you can **Debug** or **Close program**, When I choose debug, it opened a project called "deveve".

This pic show the errors that i got in EVENT VIEWER
[image: Event view photo]

Comment: Check the EventLog (type 'eventvwr' in Run) and report back with any errors found there!

Comment: I found out more than one error that the source of is called "Apps" log "Application"

Comment: post the error message that you can see in Eventlog here.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nA77W.jpg here what i got in the  EventLog errors list!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of a problem in `devenv.exe` which is the visual studio DEVelopment ENVironment.

The message just tells us something went wrong in the Visual Studio code and because it doesn't know what to do next it is shutting down visual studio to prevent it causing any damage and that details of the problem are being reported to Microsoft.  If there is a fix for the issue then it will be shown/provided to you.

The Project you get when you hit 'debug' is the same one you'll get for any executable which crashes.  It is not very useful to you as you don't know how to use it and you'd need either the source code or at least 'symbols' for the visual studio editor - neither of which are available to you.

In the event log you linked to we see that a problem was logged, but with no information about what that problem was it doesn't help and you just need to follow general troubleshooting steps.

If the problem occurs without a project open or with any project then you should try to remove and reinstall Visual Studio and ensure that all updates are properly installed.

If the problem occurs when opening a specific project then you can create a new project and import old components and class files from it until the problem returns (or doesn't.)